# jQM v1.4.0.RC.1 and popups

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with nested popups with v1.4.0.RC.1.  It works in v1.3.2.  I have a footer, which has a button, which opens a popup, which contains a listview, and one of the listitems opens a popup.  Again, in v1.3.2, this works as expected... but not with v1.4.0.RC.1.  I understand that v1.4 isn't out yet, but I pose this issue anyway as someone may have some insight that I haven't come up with yet.  I have a fiddle for both versions.  The code for each is exactly the same.  The only difference is that the first fiddle uses the 1.3.2 libraries and the second fiddle uses the v1.4.0 libraries.

Also, I have seen answers linking to a jQM popup page, showing that the page itself indicates that chaining popups isn't allowed.  However, that's typically a v1.2.0 of jQM.  The popup demo in v1.3.2 doesn't indicate that restriction, and is supported by the fact that it does in fact work (see fiddle below).

That being said, if anybody has any guidance or information, I'd really appreciate it.  I've poured through the limited 1.4.0 documentation and the interwebs and the only thing I can come up with is doing a `setTimeout` within the  `popupafterclose` event to open another popup.  That seems like a sloppy hack to me, and I'd like to avoid doing that if at all possible.

Anyway, below is code and fiddles for 1.3.2 and 1.4.0.RC.1.

Thanks!

```
<div data-role="page" id="pgMain">
<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="hdrMain" data-role="header">
    <h1>Popups from popups using jQM-1.3.2</h1>
</div>
<!-- CONTENT -->
<div data-role="content" id="contMain">
    With jQM-1.3.2, the menu button down there opens a popup window as a menu.  In the popup window is a listview, and the "Delete" listitem calls another popup to confirm deletion.<br/><br/>With jQM-1.4.0.RC.1, the second popup doesn't work.
</div>
<!-- FOOTER -->
<div id="ftrMain" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div class="ui-btn-inline ui-shadow" style="margin-left:5px; margin-right:2px;" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <a href="#mnuSelectedItemsMenu" id="btnItemMenu" data-transition="none" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-icon="bars">Menu <--- Click this...</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- POPUP: SELECTED ITEMS MENU -->
<div id="mnuSelectedItemsMenu" data-role="popup">
    <ul id="lvItemMenu" style="min-width: 210px;" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="">
        <li><a href="#" id="mnuDoEditTransaction" data-icon="edit" data-iconpos="right">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#popupConfirmDelete" id="mnuConfirmDelete" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" data-rel="popup">Delete <--- ...then this</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" style="padding:2px 0px 0px 0px;"></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="mnuDoSelectAllItems" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right">Select All</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- POPUP: CONFIRM DELETE DIALOG -->
<div id="popupConfirmDelete" class="ui-corner-all" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
    <div class="ui-corner-top" data-role="header">
        <h1>Delete Transaction</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content" data-role="content" >
        <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete these transactions?</h3>
        <p>This action cannot be undone!</p>
        <div class="ui-grid-a point6em" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a id="btnDoDeleteTransactions" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Delete</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b point6em">
                <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-mini="true">Cancel</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle for v1.3.2 above](http://jsfiddle.net/mrphuzz/RLmn4/)

```
<div data-role="page" id="pgMain">
<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="hdrMain" data-role="header">
    <h1>Popups from popups using jQM-1.4.0.RC.1</h1>
</div>
<!-- CONTENT -->
<div data-role="content" id="contMain">
    With jQM-1.3.2, the menu button down there opens a popup window as a menu.  In the popup window is a listview, and the "Delete" listitem calls another popup to confirm deletion.<br/><br/>With jQM-1.4.0.RC.1, the second popup doesn't work.
</div>
<!-- FOOTER -->
<div id="ftrMain" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div class="ui-btn-inline ui-shadow" style="margin-left:5px; margin-right:2px;" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <a href="#mnuSelectedItemsMenu" id="btnItemMenu" data-transition="none" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-icon="bars">Menu <--- Click this...</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- POPUP: SELECTED ITEMS MENU -->
<div id="mnuSelectedItemsMenu" data-role="popup">
    <ul id="lvItemMenu" style="min-width: 210px;" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="">
        <li><a href="#" id="mnuDoEditTransaction" data-icon="edit" data-iconpos="right">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#popupConfirmDelete" id="mnuConfirmDelete" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" data-rel="popup">Delete <--- ...then this</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" style="padding:2px 0px 0px 0px;"></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="mnuDoSelectAllItems" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right">Select All</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- POPUP: CONFIRM DELETE DIALOG -->
<div id="popupConfirmDelete" class="ui-corner-all" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
    <div class="ui-corner-top" data-role="header">
        <h1>Delete Transaction</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content" data-role="content" >
        <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete these transactions?</h3>
        <p>This action cannot be undone!</p>
        <div class="ui-grid-a point6em" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a id="btnDoDeleteTransactions" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Delete</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b point6em">
                <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-mini="true">Cancel</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle for v1.4.0.RC.1 above](http://jsfiddle.net/mrphuzz/2DuZ6/)

Comment: jQM 1.4 has significant changes, you will notice that many features has changed and wouldn't work the same way as in 1.3 It's really difficult to predict the problem in the absence of 1.4 API documentation. Stick to your current solution until 1.4 is officially released.

Comment: At the moment (2014-02-03) http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/ states that "Chaining of popups not allowed: it's not possible to embed a link from one popup to another popup. All links with a data-rel="popup" inside a popup will not do anything at all"